# Is there an alternative for :has()?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am rendering my content via v-html and I need to get span that has img element, so I could specifically add style style to span. :has() is supported in latest browser. Are there ant alternatives?

Comment: Yes, loop all elements and find only ones that contains image.

Comment: Yee, but looping all elements isn`t the best solution, is there any else?

Comment: Yes, there is `:has()` for newer browsers

Comment: Hi, please make an effort regarding your question next time. This is not meeting the standards. [ask]